# Excel Nest Round Up Function to 100th

Tags: excel, if-statement, rounding

I have the results of this function =B2/25000*91000 in cell B1,  How would I round the answer up to 100th place

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out ...

=CEILING.MATH(B1,100)